# Trying to filter an array of strings to return a single field which is a subset of the array with strings that contain a variable

Tags: neo4j, cypher

The DB has items, and these items have a string parameter which is a comma separated string array. Im trying to pass in a search variable, and use that to return the item node, and the string array but with only the strings that match the search variable

```
match (n:Node) return n.string
```

returns the strings sorted by the item node as ["abc,def,abcde"]

```
match (n:Node)  where any(string in n.string where string contains "abc") return n
```

This gets me the nodes where one of the strings contains what I'm looking for, but I can't seem to find a way to get the ones which matched and return them as a field

So if a node has a string of ["abc","def","abcde"] then when I search for strings containing "bc" then it should get the node and return just the strings of ["abc","abcde"]

Comment: pls give us an example. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query returns each node and its list of filtered strings. Nodes without matching strings are ignored. `$filter` is a [parameter](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/) with the desired filter (e.g., "abc").

```
MATCH (n:Node)
UNWIND n.string AS s
WITH n, s
WHERE s CONTAINS $filter
RETURN n, COLLECT(s) AS filtered_strings
```

NOTE: If `n.string` is actually a string that looks like a list, replace `n.string` with `SPLIT(n.string, ',')`.

Comment: Thought this wasn't working but turns out that the field I'm working with is actually a single string with speech marks and commas, so looked like an array of strings. Once I did the UNWIND I did a SPLIT(s,",) AS x and used that and it all worked, many thanks

Comment: Correct. It should be split(n.string, ',') as s  in line 2. thanks.